# Removing character from regexp class in R

Tags: regex, r, regex-negation

*Edit*: Changing the whole question to make it clearer.

Can I remove a single character from one of the regular expression classes in R (such as `[:alnum:]`)?

For example, match all punctuation (`[:punct:]`) except the `_` character.

I am trying the replace underscores used in markdown for italicizing but the italicized substring may contain a single underscore which I would want to keep.

*Edit*: As another example, I want to capture everything between pairs of underscores (note one pair contains a single underscore that I want to keep between 1 and 10)

```
This is _a random_ string with _underscores: rate 1_10 please_
```

Comment: Please help us to help you by providing more informations and specify what or when or where underscores you want to keep are located or occurs etc.

Comment: If R supports negative Posix classes you could do it with a negative-negative like `[^[:^alnum:]a]` but I think the negative Posix class is a Perl extension. It might be worth a try though. Alternatively, you could do `[[:alnum:]](?<!a)`

Comment: Basically, the bottom line is your not going to be able to differentiate the start underscore from the end underscore without help from external cue's that parse the entire form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't believe it, but [lazy matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) achieved with a mere `?` works as expected here:

```
str <- 'This is a _string with_ some _random underscores_ in it.'
gsub("_+([[:print:]]+?)_+", "\\1", str)
str <- 'This is a _random string with_ a scale of 1_10.'
gsub("_+([[:print:]]+?)_+", "\\1", str)
```

Result:

```
[1] "This is a string with some random underscores in it."
[1] "This is a random string with a scale of 1_10."
```

Here is the [demo program](http://ideone.com/TAmHrp)

**However**, if you want to modify the [`[[:print:]]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) class, mind it is basically a `[\x20-\x7E]` range. The underscore being `\x5F`, you can easily exclude it from the range, and use `[\x20-\x5E\x60-\x7E]`.

```
str <- 'This is a _string with_ some _random underscores_ in it.'
gsub("_+([\x20-\x5E\x60-\x7E]+)_+", "\\1", str)
```

[Returns](http://ideone.com/caUfUi)

```
[1] "This is a string with some random underscores in it."
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @stribizhev:

```
x <- "This is _a random_ string with _underscores: rate 1_10 please_"
gsub("\\b_(.*?)_\\b", "\\1", x, perl=T)
```

produces:

```
[1] "This is a random string with underscores: rate 1_10 please"
```

Here we use word boundaries and lazy matching.  Note that the default regexp engine has issues with lazy repetition and capture groups, so you may want to use `perl=T`

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('(?<=\\D)\\_(?=\\D|$)','',str,perl=T)
```